# os.rename() function is causing a FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, file, import, rename

I was study the `import os` today, I working with a rename code.

```
import os

PictureFolder = "G:\VSCode\PythonVS\WorkPicture"
i = 1
def renameFile():
    for filename in os.listdir(PictureFolder):
        global i
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext == ".jpg":
            os.rename(filename, str(f"{i:03}") + ".jpg")
            i += 1
        else:
            print("Processing")

renameFile()
```

and it was error due to:

```
FileNotFoundError
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'B.jpg' -> '001.jpg'
```

So I was confused with the error cause I don't know what am I doing wrong.

This is the Folder I was working with:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `os.listdir` only returns the file *names*, not the full path. You have to prepend the directory name to each file name, e.g. `path = os.path.join(PictureFolder, filename)`, and then use `path`. Be aware that the same goes for the renamed file, otherwise the renamed files will end up in whatever the current workding directory (from where the Python script is execued) is.

Comment: Try to change all slash from this \ to this /

Comment: `B.jpg` does not exist _in the current directory_.  It's in `G:\VSCode\PythonVS\WorkPicture`.  You did not provide the full path in the call to `os.rename()`.

Comment: Note that a path like `"G:\VSCode\PythonVS\WorkPicture"` can become problematic. Follow Matteo's suggestion and replace the backslahes with forward slashes (Python handles this correctly under the hood), escape each slash (by doubling it), or use a raw string, by prepending the string with an 'r': `r"G:\VSCode\PythonVS\WorkPicture"`.

Comment: These are all great information for me! thank you everyone for telling me what I didn't know in python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os

PictureFolder = r"G:\VSCode\PythonVS\WorkPicture"
os.chdir(PictureFolder)
i = 1
def renameFile():
    for filename in os.listdir(PictureFolder):
        global i
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext == ".jpg":
            os.rename(filename, str(f"{i:03}") + ".jpg")
            i += 1
        else:
            print("Processing")

renameFile()
```

Edit:

```
os.chdir(path): Change the current working directory to path.
```

Comment: This is working now, thank you for your help! but if you have time I just wonder what's (os.chdir) do?

Comment: Meary9: It's in the documentation.

Comment: @meary9 I edited post. More info on this can be found on the python doc page as @ martinaeu said. Thank you